# How to Send data from Android app to a Server date?

Tags: android, gps, tracking

I'm A beginner Developer, I'm making an android GPS tracking app, i made it to collect the lat and the long, also i can bring the Phone number and the IMEI To the Phone Screen, my question is how can i send those data to a server which I need to use so i can trace users on a Google map, this is my first Question & i Hope i was clear enough for you to understand my needs thank you .

(this is my code below , i add a Post data try by it doesn't work )

```
    package com.exemple.travelinsave;


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class PrincipalActivity extends Activity {

    TextView Textlat; //= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textlat);
    TextView Textlong; //= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textlong);

    TextView EditNum; //= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textlat);
    TextView EditIMEI; //= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textlong);

     private final String TAG = "DemoButtonApp";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        Textlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Textlat);
        Textlong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Textlong);

        EditNum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditNum);
        EditIMEI = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditIMEI);

        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String IMEINum = manager.getDeviceId();
        String phonenum = manager.getLine1Number();

        EditIMEI.setText(IMEINum);
        EditNum.setText(phonenum);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener ();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);


       SetupsendButton();

    }


    class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener{



        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(location !=null)
            {   
                double pLat = location.getLatitude();
                double pLong = location.getLongitude();

                Textlat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
                Textlong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));

            }

        }



    }




        private void SetupsendButton() {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Button SendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
                SendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //Log.i(TAG, "You clicked the bottuon!");
                        //Toast.makeText(PrincipalActivity.this, "You Clicked it ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        try {
                            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                            String postURL = "http://cybergracz.com/wp-includes/post.php";
                            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
                                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);

                                Textlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Textlat);
                                Textlong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Textlong);

                                EditNum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditNum);
                                EditIMEI = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditIMEI);

                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneNUM", String.valueOf(EditNum.getText())));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Latitude ", String.valueOf(Textlat.getText())));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Longitude", String.valueOf(Textlong.getText())));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DeviceID", String.valueOf(EditIMEI.getText())));

                                UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
                                post.setEntity(ent);
                                HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
                                HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
                                if (resEntity != null) {    
                                    Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                                }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                         try {
                            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  

                            Textlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Textlat);
                             Textlong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Textlong);

                               EditNum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditNum);
                              EditIMEI = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditIMEI);

                              String PostDatS = "EditNum=" + EditNum;
                              PostDatS = PostDatS + "EditIMEI=" + EditIMEI;
                              PostDatS = PostDatS + "Textlat=" + Textlat;
                              PostDatS = PostDatS + "Textlong=" + Textlong;

                              String postURL = "http://starcitydirt.com/get.php?" + PostDatS;
                              HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
                                  List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "kris"));
                                  UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
                                   post.setEntity(ent);
                                   HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
                                   HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
                                  if (resEntity != null) {    
                                      Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                                  }
                          } catch (Exception e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }

                    }


            });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.principal, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: you should only ask one question in one post. Here are 2 totally independent questions.

Comment: Well anyone can help ?

Comment: Thank you , well i want to send lat, long , Phone Num , IMEI Num To a server !! i tried some codes from the forum but i think i'm screwing up with something ,cause when i check my logGet i just can't found nothing there so nothing was sent , So please tell me what i need to make it work cause this is for school project and i'm running of time .

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `postData();` in onCreate. You haven't received any position at this point.

You have to move `postData();` to when you actually receive a Location, i.e. in onLocationChanged.

You'll also probably need to put that in an AsyncTask.

Comment: will you check the Source code now , i add a Button to See if it's going to work but it doesn't sames to me, about the AsyncTask I'm still googling it to understand more , Please Forgive my Ignorance thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Recently a lot of people are asking questions that resemble `android app to send data to a server`. Although this is a basic programming question something that should be google'd, I'll try to provide some direction for the developer to google.

**Option 1**

Develop a J2EE webservice, and host it on a server. Your Android app needs to associate data with the webservice and send it to the server. The server can receive the data and do what it wants to with it. The server can also process and respond some more information through the same response of the webservice. You need to google for `hello world j2ee`. I found [one](http://solutions.devx.com/ibm/skillbuilding/archives/developing-and-testing-a-complete-j2ee-hello-world-app-with-websphere-studio-v5.html).

Once your J2EE is working on a local desktop (or development machine), you can copy the WAR or EAR to a EC2 to make the application workable over the internet, without having to go through the pain of creating a network that is open and a DMZ.

**Option 2**

You can develop a java socket based product, which your android app connects to, thru clientsocket. This way you can serialize data and send it over a stream. And on the server end deserialize it and reconstruct the object. This approach needs more disciplined software development. It can be very buggy if you are a first time developer, I would recommend Option 1.

Hope I have given some basic direction.

Comment: the app is collecting Lat , long , and device Info and i need a way to send data to my php file via http request : post or getdata like this File.php?info1=value1&info2=value2 and thank you for your time

Comment: http://website.com/LogGetDt.txt

http://website.com/get.php?deviceid=31231313131313213132&devicenum=212625124423&lant=14.215465464&long=5.254654654654